# Using a fixed server ID with OOkla speedtest-cli

Tags: speed-test

Some time ago, I set up a Linux task to run speedtest-cli every 30 minutes to figure out a network issue. The task used the "--server ID" argument to get the speed to the same server each time. I used it for a while then forgot about it. Today I go back to revisit this only to find out that the API seems to have changed. Now proving the --list argument does not print a list of hundreds of servers, but of only the few (~10) nearest you. In my case, the servers it reports seems to change at least daily. Requesting speedtest to any server ID not reported in the list gives a failure. Has anyone figured out a way to get a periodic speedtest to a fixed server using speedtest-cli or any other tool?

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for a solution, here is my suggestion.

While this does not use speedtest-cli (which no longer is supported and you should look at Ookla SpeedTest command line client instead) I believe this is what you are looking for, I'm running this in a Debian VM but if you have access to a RPi and can dedicate to this task, you may want to check this out.

https://github.com/geerlingguy/internet-pi

You can modify the docker-compose to hard code the server ID of your choice. You can get this from the Ookla SpeedTest command line client.

You would need to run the command:

```
speedtest -L
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

The only proper way to do what you need, is by using the official speedtest application.

Find it here: https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli#ubuntu . Firstly, uninstall the speedtest-cli.

Use this api call to find the server id of the server you want

```
https://www.speedtest.net/api/js/servers?engine=js&https_functional=true&limit=100&search={put_the_country_name_of_the_server_you_want_here}
```

for example https://www.speedtest.net/api/js/servers?engine=js&https_functional=true&limit=100&search=Greece

Then use `speedtest -s {the id}`

for example speedtest -s 5188